# Form submission for logging in with perl

Tags: perl, authentication, mechanize

I installed DVWA and got on to try the challenges (all the database/configs are done correctly) and the login creds on localhost are admin:password. these work when I am trying to login manually.

I would like to write a perl script to bruteforce the bruteforce login challenge, however I cannot get to that page.

I use the following code to login in login.php, but it doesn't work. I am using Mechanize (previously used UserAgent pm but failed, so moved to this one after endless google searches)

```
1 #! /usr/bin/perl
2 
3 use WWW::Mechanize ;
4 
5 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck =>1);
6 $mech->credentials('admin'=>'password');
7 $mech->get('http://localhost/dvwa/login.php');
8 print $mech->content();
```

the 8th line prints the contents of the login page. What is wrong with my code and what should I do to access the main page? Should I manually redirect to it after logging in ??

Comment: You may want to change the title of your post to reflect your problem, not what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The `credentials` method is for HTTP authentication. This is a form submit, so you need to fill out the form first.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# ^ no space between #! and the perl binary

# always include these or I will hunt you down in your sleep:
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );
$mech->get( 'http://localhost/dvwa/login.php' );

# you'll need to look at the login page HTML to get the actual field names
$mech->field( username => 'admin' );
$mech->field( password => 'password' );

$mech->submit;

print $mech->decoded_content;   # instead of ->content
```

If there is more than one form on that page, you may need to get more specific with the `field` and `submit` methods; see the excellent [Mechanize form-handling documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#FORM-METHODS).

Comment: nope, still won't login. Although that was a very helpful clarification ! I managed to get it to login by using UserAgent though !

Comment: WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent. It can do anything UserAgent can do.

Comment: I know, I just implied that my initial implementation worked. Now I am faced with the problem of getting the redirect page from the Location field in the response header, which is index.php (correctly !)